# How to use a second placeholder initial condition in the example?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I would like to use the following code for 2d parametric plot of 4d ode system. For the plot I need initial points to be gridded for 2 state variables. So I need to have 2 placeholders #1 and #2, which will pick values from two sequences simultaneously. Hopefully it will produce something like this image.

[image: image of parametric plot]

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. 
     NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -.26 Sin[x[t]], x[0] == 0, 
        y[0] == #}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, -30, 30}][[
      1]] & /@ {-3.5, -3, -2, -1.7, 
    Sequence @@ Range[-1.5, -1, .2], -1.02, 
    Sequence @@ Range[0, 1.5, .2], 1.02, 1.7, 2, 3, 3.5}
  ], {t, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-2, 2}}, PlotStyle -> Red,
 AxesLabel -> {x, ""},
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  TextCell[Style["pendulum", Italic], PageWidth -> 100, 
   TextAlignment -> Center]]
```

The only placeholder is in initial condition of y. If I want to have initial condition of x also, to be chosen from a sequence, how to change the code?

Comment: One possibility: define your "placeholder" as a pair {init1,init2} and then set {x[[0]],y[[0]]}=#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sol := NDSolve[
    {x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -13/50 Sin[x[t]],
     x[0] == #1, y[0] == #2}, {x, y}, {t, -30, 30}][[1]] &

x0 = {-3.5, -3, 1.02, 1.7};
y0 = {1.02, 1.7, 3, 3.5};

ics = Transpose[{x0, y0}];

ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. (sol @@@ ics)],
 {t, -20, 20},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel ->
  (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x[t], y[t]}),
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotLegends ->
  (StringForm["x0=``, y0=``", #[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ ics),
 PlotLabel -> TextCell[Style["pendulum", Italic],
   PageWidth -> 100,
   TextAlignment -> Center]]
```

[image]

Comment: It works superbly for my model. But how can I have same coloured lines converging to same point (like the example)?

Comment: @SDas - use a different model?